# Website title is repositioned when body text is inserted

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, clip-path

I'm creating a website header that is an image in the shape of a trapezoid with the website title on top of it. It looks the way I want until I insert a text content under it in the main body section. When I do that, the title moves down and is not centred in the image anymore.

I have created a CodePen pen to show what I mean, instead of using an image, I just gave the header dimensions and colour:
 `width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;`

I tried to play with floats, I enclosed the header in its own section, but I can't figure out what is going on.

This is the link to the CodePen: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FairyCodeMother/pen/PmNamJ?editors=1100)

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your **.header** `position:relative` and it will work.

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0% 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

  position:relative;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/sahildhir_1/pen/xdVzyV?editors=1100) is the updated codepen.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours on this and all it took was one line of code.

Comment: You are welcome :) its happens sometime. Hope this things will help you in future projects too .